# Comparing Lists with different sizes and Putting Matching Results into a Markdown file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, markdown, systemd

I am stuck with a problem in Python, while comparing lists with different sizes. 
As title mentions, I have a list of the titles for a markdown report file.
The rows should be arranged in a way where each column matches with its correspondent title.

I am reading the records from a file that has a structure like this:

```
|Filename=timer|Description=Signal Timer|OnBootSec=5min|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target|
|Filename=activator|Description=activator timer|OnBootSec=3min|OnUnitActiveSec=1hr|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target|WantedBy=some.target|
|Filename=mode|Description=mode timer|OnBootSec=4min|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target|
|Filename=reset|Description=reset timer|After=some.service|PartOf=some.service|OnActiveSec=1min|Unit=sometime.service|WantedBy=some.target|
```

I read this file and prepare it for the markdown format.
The code I have for it has some missing points. Yet, I would like to share.

```
report = open (output,"w+")
    for i in range(0,len(titles)):
        report.write(titles[i]+"|")
    report.write("\n")
    report.close
    for i in range(0,len(titles)):
        report.write("|------")
    report.write("|\n")
    report.close
    for i in range(0,len(titles)):
        if (titles[i]==aList[i][1][0]):
            report.write(aList[i][1][0] +'='+ aList[i][1][1])
        else:
            report.write("|")
    report.close
```

After formatting in the last for loop I was trying to compare and put additional "|" between in order to create a field with no elements.

Apart from that aList has such structure:

```
[0, ['WantedBy', 'some.target|\n']]
```

Basically, the first element is the group number and each record with a same group number will be written on same line. Second element set includes a key/value pair. That's why I am putting "=" sign between them.

Desired markdown output is a table:

```
|Filename|Description|OnBootSec|Unit|WantedBy|OnUnitActiveSec|After|PartOf|
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|Filename=timer|Description=Signal Timer|OnBootSec=5min|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target|
|Filename=activator|Description=activator timer|OnBootSec=3min|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target WantedBy=some.target|OnUnitActiveSec=1hr|||
|Filename=mode|Description=mode timer|OnBootSec=4min|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target|
|Filename=reset|Description=reset timer|OnActiveSec=1min|Unit=sometime.service|WantedBy=some.target||After=some.service|PartOf=some.service|
```

I appreciate your time and feedback.

Regards

P.S. You might want to check the output on http://dillinger.io/

Comment: How is alist defined/set up? Can you show that code?

Comment: Here it is:
`arrangedList = []
 temp = []
 for key, value in dict.items():
  temp = [key,value]
  arrangedList.append(temp)` 
Basically, from a dictionary.

Comment: Wow! That's counterproductive. See below.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a simplified version. On some steps, we transferred data between different data structures. ~3kloc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your problem seems to be: Use a Dictionary.

Let's first rewrite some of your existing code to be a little more Pythonic, and readable. The top couple of lines are sample data, and I've reset the report file to just print to stdout, but other than that, I think this is a bit easier to work with:

```
titles = """
|Filename|Description|OnBootSec|Unit|WantedBy|OnUnitActiveSec|After|PartOf|
""".strip().split('|')[1:-1]

aRecord="""
|Filename=activator|Description=activator timer|OnBootSec=3min|Unit=some.service|WantedBy=some.target WantedBy=some.target|OnUnitActiveSec=1hr|||
""".strip().split('|')
aList = [('alist[_][0]?', f.split('=')) for f in aRecord if f]


import sys
with sys.stdout as report:
#with open(output, 'w+') as report:
    # Print header
    print('|'.join(titles), file=report)
    print('|'.join('-' * len(t) for t in titles), file=report)

    format_str = '|'.join('{{:<{}s}}'.format(len(t)) for t in titles)

    # Convert aList into a dictionary
    record = dict((f[1][0],f[1][1]) for f in aList)

    # Print rows
    print(format_str.format(*(record.get(fld, '') for fld in titles), file=report))
```

You'll notice I convert aList into a dictionary. Based on your comments, there is already a dictionary with those values, so I think you can just eliminate the middle man.

I didn't bother printing the field name, since the title of the column already has that info.

Comment: This is valuable! Thank you, I will work on it. Regards